# Who is this goblin like character in the Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-phantom-menace

At the celebration after the victory at Naboo, there is a Harry Potter-esque goblin standing next to Yoda. Who is this guy?

[image]

Comment: What nice curtains...

Comment: I'm also wondering what you won the trophy for...

Comment: Wife picked the curtains and the award is for the eldest, star pupil last week.

Comment: Pink Yoda.  He's Pink Yoda.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is Jedi Master [Even Piell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Even_Piell). The factbook "Ultimate Star Wars" identifies his species as being [Lannik](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lannik_(species))

He was present during several key decisions taken by the Council in the first two Star Wars films including Anakin's original testing by Mace Windu.

[image]

He also features in the Clone Wars cartoon TV series where he

> [died](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1HYQuDr5h8)

[image]

Comment: He also appears in episodes 62 to 64 of _Star Wars: The Clone Wars_, where he is prisoner of the separatists and a team of Jedy is sent to try and free him.

Comment: Tel me more about these Jedy....

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - Everyone's a cricket

Comment: How embarrassing ... I _knew_ it looked strange written that way, but I couldn't see where the error was! :-) (I blame the dark side)

Comment: Is Jedy the plural of Jedi?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Only in Tolkien's original draft.

Comment: Should also note that the Lannik weren't generally as ugly as Piell. Most Lannik men resembled dwarves with lots of immaculately-groomed facial hair & braiding. The fact that Piell kept himself clean-shaven, along with his gruesome facial scarring, made him pretty nasty-looking by Lannik standards. Not that he cared, cuz he's all Zen-Fu and stuff.